# Fan works hard while `yarn start`

Tags: fan, cpu-usage, web-development, npm, react.js

I build websites with ReactJs, npm, yarn, etc.

When I do `yarn start` and check websites in development with `localhost`, the fan of my Mac works hard, and the noise is annoying.

Does anyone have any solution to smooth this?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Obviously your system is experiencing an intensive load or at least your Mac thinks so. Before following any advice I give below please open Activity Monitor while running one of your projects and make sure something doesn't spike. If something is spiking that's why your fans are turning on.

You can [download this software](https://crystalidea.com/macs-fan-control/download) which allows you to control your Mac's fans. **Be careful not to turn the fans on too high or too low**. You can select a fan and choose how fast it should run (RPM).

Comment: I have not tried... Let's accept this answer for the moment...